# Passing model from parent view to partial view (MVC 5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view with a model, and inside that view I call a partial view. I'm currently actually able to access the model from inside the partial view without passing any parameters, and from what I read online, that shouldn't be possible. Everywhere I see, they say to pass the model parameter when calling the partial view. So my question is, should this be working? Can a partial view actually access everything from the parent view directly?

I declare the model in the parent view like this:

```
@model ClienteFornecedorDTO
```

and call the partial view like this inside the parent view:

```
<div class="form-group">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Fornecedor.InscricaoMunicipal, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
       <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Fornecedor.InscricaoMunicipal, new { htmlAttributes = vFormControlHtmlAttributes})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Fornecedor.InscricaoMunicipal, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
</div>
@Html.Partial("EstadoCidadeDDL")
```

When I call the Model inside my partial view, all the values are there:

```
@{    

    CidadeDTO cidade = new CidadeDTO();
    cidade.IdEstado = ViewBag.EstadoSelectedId != null ? ViewBag.EstadoSelectedId : 0;
    bool vCanUpdate = ViewContext.CanUpdate();
    object vFormControlHtmlAttributes;

    if (ViewContext.Profile().IdentityUser.AppRoles.Any(x => x.SystemTotalAccess == true) || (vCanUpdate && Model.Fornecedor.Tipo != EmpresaFuncao.Cliente))
    {
        vFormControlHtmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "CarregaCidades(this.value)" };
    }
    else
    {
        vFormControlHtmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "true" };
    }

 }
```

But from what I could read online, I should be doing something like this when calling my partial view:

```
@Html.Partial("EstadoCidadeDDL", Model)
```

Comment: You got the solution, so where is the problem?

Comment: Everywhere I looked said my solution shouldn't be possible, so I don't know if I can trust it

Comment: You should follow standard pattern to avoid future surprises  and pass model to partial view.

Answer (score 1):

// Parent view
// index.cshtml

```
@model  WebApplication5.Models.Student
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@Html.Partial("_SampleTest", Model)
```

// Partial view
// _SampleTest.cshtml

```
@model WebApplication5.Models.Student
<h1>@Model.ID</h1>
```